# Django finding the path of the file problem

Tags: python, django

```
skin
  -mysite
      -myapp
         -templates
             -index.html
         -mysite
             -urls.py
             -settings.py
         -admin.py
         -views.py
```

I create the virtual environment in

```
~/home/env
```

and the index.html is located in

```
/home/jake/Gits/skin/mysite/myapp/templates/index.html
```

```
views.py 
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

```
url.py

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp import views as v
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', v.index),
]
```

```
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

and the this Django project did not find the right path

> TemplateDoesNotExist at / index.html Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Django Version:  1.8.1 Exception
>   Type: TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value:    index.html Exception
>   Location: /home/jake/Gits/skin/mysite/myapp/views.py in index, line 6
>   Python Executable:    /home/jake/Gits/skin/bin/python Python
>   Version:  3.7.3 Python Path:   ['/home/jake/Gits/skin/mysite',
>   '/home/jake/Gits/skin/lib/python37.zip',
>   '/home/jake/Gits/skin/lib/python3.7',
>   '/home/jake/Gits/skin/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
>   '/home/jake/anaconda3/lib/python3.7',
>   '/home/jake/Gits/skin/lib/python3.7/site-packages'] Server time:  Wed,
>   8 Jan 2020 06:47:32 +0000 Template-loader postmortem Django tried
>   loading these templates, in this order:
>
> Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: Using loader
>   django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
>   /home/jake/Gits/skin/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/index.html
>   (File does not exist)
>   /home/jake/Gits/skin/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/index.html
>   (File does not exist) Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
>   /home/jake/Gits/skin/mysite/myapp/views.py in index
>                   return render_to_response('index.html') ... ▶ Local vars

Comment: can you show your template settings in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

With minimal change ..

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...., ## Your other settings
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),'templates'], ## Little change here
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...., ## Your other settings
    },
]
```

Please let me know if there is still an error.

Comment: my base dir is    
 BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Comment: my settings and templates is in a different directory

Comment: In your settings.py put this command "print(BASE_DIR)" and restart your development server. In the console it will print out the BASE_DIR. You will have a better idea where it is looking for

Answer (score 0):

In right way your project directory structure should look like this:

> YourFolder
>
> > -Yourapp
> >
> > > -urls.py
> > >
> > > -settings.py
> >
> > -templates
> >
> > > index.html
> >
> > -staticfiles
> >      -manage.py

It seems that your variable in settings.py(BASE_DIR) - home/You/Gits/skin/mysite/.
There is 2 solution. 1.Change your BASE_DIR variable. 2. change your templates location.

But my advice, create project properly according to documentation.